# Using fixed char[] to copy data and creating string from it, not always using entire char[], safe?

Tags: c#

So i noticed that manipulating `Strings` is super slow when it comes to anything that causes it to resize, basically removing or adding character (in my case removing).

So i figured that using a `stackalloc` or fixed temporary buffer and just copy all data to it except what i don't want equals the same thing as removing.

But i need to allocate the same length for this buffer, cause that's the limit,
it can never be greater than it, but it is surely lower.

So here is the code, I wonder if this way of doing it is actually safe,
cause there can be much of the buffer that's never used.

```
    //Remove all unneccessery empty spaces
    private unsafe static string FormatCodeUnsafe(string text)
    {

        int length = text.Length;
        var charbuffer = new char[length];
        int index = 0;
        fixed (char* charbuf = charbuffer)
        fixed (char* strptr = text)
        {
            char* charptr = charbuf;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                char c = strptr[i];

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    if (c == ' ' && strptr[i - 1] == ',')
                        continue;

                    if (c == ' ' && strptr[i - 1] == ')')
                        continue;
                    if (c == ' ' && strptr[i - 1] == ' ')
                        continue;
                }
                if (i < length - 1)
                {
                    if (c == ' ' && strptr[i + 1] == ' ')
                        continue;
                    if (c == ' ' && strptr[i + 1] == ',')
                        continue;
                    if (c == ' ' && strptr[i + 1] == '(')
                        continue;
                }

                *charptr = c;
                charptr++;
                index++;
            }
        }
        //Return the result
        return new string(charbuffer, 0, index);
    }
```

EDIT:

Hard to choose between the answers as both give good examples and explanation.
I would like to choose both for helping out, but well i have to choose one.

Thanks!:)

Comment: I think that your code does not give desired result if the input contains consecutive spaces as they will be all removed. So `abc  def` would returns `abcdef` if there is more than one space between words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating `strings` is slow, because strings are **immutable** - each time you add concatenate or replace parts of the string a new string gets created.

Because `string` manipulation is very common, there is another class in the .NET Framework - `StringBuilder`, which allows you to do this **very efficiently** (it is **mutable**) and when you are done, you can get the resulting `string` by calling the `ToString()` method on the `StringBuilder` instance.

Your code could look like this:

```
private static readonly char[] SkipCharacters = new[] {',', '(', ')'};

//Remove all unneccessery empty spaces
private static string FormatCode(string text)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var character = text[i];
        //set defaults - so that we do not have to check
        //for the start and end of the string
        char previous = 'x';
        char next = 'x';
        if (i > 0)
        {
            previous = text[i - 1];
        }
        if (i < text.Length - 1)
        {
            next = text[i + 1];
        }
        if ( character == ' ' &&
                SkipCharacters.Contains( previous ) ||
                SkipCharacters.Contains( next ) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        builder.Append( character );
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Using **unsafe** code might be a little faster than this managed approach, but the performance gain is hindered by the fact that you could potentially be **wasting a lot of space** (for the whole text-sized array) and are using **potentially dangerous** and **less maintainable code**. That said, if your benchmarks show `unsafe` has significantly better performance, there is nothing stopping you from using it if you are careful :-) .

Comment: I know the Stringbuilder, but could you elaborate how it could be dangerous with using the way i do.
What happens if i don't use the whole buffer, will it get stuck somewhere, or will it just be cleaned up after the function?

Comment: The unused space will definitely get cleaned up after the method finishes (thanks to the garbage collector), so you don't have to worry about it getting stuck. The "danger" is just the fact that you need to use `unsafe`, which is always better to avoid in case a managed solution is not significantly slower (which should not be with `StringBuilder`). That said, if your benchmarks show that the `unsafe` method is visibly faster, there is surely nothing stopping you from using it :-) .

Comment: `FormatCodeUnsafe` should be renamed as it is not `unsafe` anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Well, If I have to code that, I would do something similar to this... The exact implementation could vary depending on how you want to handle consecutive spaces. This code assume that we want to trim leading and trailing space and merge inner spaces.

I have put some extra explanation in the code to help understanding of the code.

```
string FormatCode(string input)
{
    int indexSpace = input.IndexOf(' ');

    if (indexSpace == -1)
    {
        // If the string does not contains any space, return it as it.
        return input;
    }

    // The index from where we want to append data...
    int index = 0;

    // Preallocate memory using old size as the starting point...
    var builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

    while(true)
    {
        // Append everything before the current space...
        builder.Append(input.Substring(index, indexSpace - index));

        // Decide if we want to keep that space...

        // Do not keep initial spaces...
        bool needSpace = indexSpace > 0;

        if (needSpace)
        {
            // Do not keep space after selected symbols...
            switch (input[indexSpace - 1])
            {
                case ',':
                case ')':
                    needSpace = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Find the next character that is not a space as we always want
        // to merge consecutives spaces and detecting them help handle 
        // edge cases.
        int indexNotSpace = indexSpace;
        while (++indexNotSpace < input.Length && input[indexNotSpace] == ' ')
        {
        }

        if (indexNotSpace == input.Length)
        {
            // The remaining of the string consist only of spaces...
            break;
        }

        if (needSpace)
        {
            // Do not keep spaces before selected symbols...
            switch (input[indexSpace + 1])
            {
                case ',':
                case '(':
                    needSpace = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (needSpace)
        {
            builder.Append(' ');
        }

        // Find next space not already processed...
        index = indexNotSpace;
        indexSpace = input.IndexOf(' ', index);

        if (indexSpace == -1)
        {
            // There are not remaining space so append remaining text 
            // and exit loop.
            builder.Append(input.Substring(index));
            break;
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

**That code will give different result than original code in some cases but I think that original code do not give expected result in some cases**.

Let use ~ to represent spaces.

```
input     : abc~~def
OP output : abcdef
My output : abc~def

input     : ~abc~
OP output : ~abc~
My output : abc

input     : ~~~(~~test~~)~~~
OP output : (test)
My output : (~test~)

input     : (~~~~~~)
OP output : ()
My output : (~)
```

Comment: Interesting, i do think that my output is correct (for my usecase),
except for the second example, though it would be rare in my case i didn't spot it.

Great example:)

Comment: Well, it would be weird that `abc def` (one space) would keep the space while `abc  def` (two or more spaces) would remove them all.